# java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set - Spring Test and Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, spring-test

my test return failed with error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set
```

I read that this error don't mean so much, because return the same if there is a NPE or don't match the handler ...
But i don't understand where is the error, seem to me all ok ...

My controller is already with `@RestController` 
This is controller Method:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/local")
    public class ControllerTest{
    .....
            @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            @ResponseBody
            public JsonResponse<TestResponseModel> test (
                    @RequestParam(value = "data1", required = true) String data1,
                    @RequestParam(value = "data2", required = true) String data2,
            {
                try {
                    TestRequestModel input= new TestRequestModel();
                    input.setData1(data1);
                    input.setData2(data2);
                    TestResponseModel entities = business.test(input);
                    return JsonResponse(entities);
                } catch (TestException e) {
                    log.error("APPLICATION EXCEPTION", e);
                    throw e;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("UNHANDLED EXCEPTION", e);
                    throw new TestException(e);
                }
            }
}
```

and this is the test:

```
    @Mock
    private Business business;
    @Mock
    private TestResponseModel testResponseModel;

    @Test
    public void getTest() throws Exception {
        when(business.test(isA(TestRequestModel.class))).thenReturn(testResponseModel);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/local/test")
                .requestAttr("data1", "data1_test")
                .requestAttr("data2", "data2_test"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"));
    }
```

StackTrace:

```
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:35)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertTrue(AssertionErrors.java:65)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ContentResultMatchers$1.match(ContentResultMatchers.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.applyDefaultResultActions(MockMvc.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:163)
    at com.test.controller.TestClassTest.GetTest(TestClassTest.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:68)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:74)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more of the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed changing in Test Unit `.requestAttr()` to `.param()`